# Require JSON as deep copy

Tags: node.js, json, testing, fixtures

I am writing tests right now for my node application.
I have fixtures which I use to test my data and I ran into the Problem, that when I alter any of them in a method, then they are globally altered for all the other tests as well, which obviously has to do with referencing. Now I figured if I write my fixtures into a JSON and require that JSON in each file then they will have unique references for each file, which turns out now, they don't. 
My question would be: is there an easy way to handle fixtures in Node such that every file has an instance of the fixtures which won't affect the other test files.

The way I currently import my fixtures in every test file:

```
const {fixture1, someOtherFixture } = require('../../../../../fixtures/keywords.json');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` calls are cached, so once you call it, consecutive calls will return the same object.

You can do the following:

```
const {fixture1, someOtherFixture } = require('../../../../../fixtures/keywords.json');

const fixtureCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fixture1));
const someOtherFixtureCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someOtherFixtureCopy));
```

or use a package:

- [deepcopy](http://deepcopy)
- [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone)

```
const deepcopy = require('deepcopy');
const {fixture1, someOtherFixture } = require('../../../../../fixtures/keywords.json');

const fixtureCopy = deepcopy(fixture1);
const someOtherFixtureCopy = deepcopy(someOtherFixtureCopy);
```

Or change your module to export a function that will return new copies everytime. This is the recommended approach in my opinion.

```
module.exports = {
   get() {
      return deepcopy(fixture); // fixture being the Object you have 
   }
}
```

```
const fixture = require('./fixture');

const fixture1 = fixture.get();
```

Comment: Yes I thought about doing that, it would add another step to each of my tests and would make them look a little bit less clean imo. Is there any way you know of I can bypass an extra step and already ensure that the require step makes a deep copy? Like using filesystem for example?

Comment: No, `require` calls are cached. Check updated answer.

Comment: Very good idea using a method that makes a deep copy as proxy, will do that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to JSON. It's not uncommon that modules need to be re-evaluated in tests. `require.cache` can be modified in Node.js to affect how modules are cached, either directly or with helpers like `decache`.

Depending on the case,

```
decache('../../../../../fixtures/keywords.json')
```

goes before `require` in a test, or to `afterEach` to clean up.

Comment: and this will not have any side effects except making sure the objects don't override each other?

Comment: Generally, yes, there are no negative side effects.